# find a plane perpendicular to a line and a certain distance from the origin

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, geometry

We have a line

$$ \frac{x}{2} = \frac{y+4}{2} = z-3$$

We need to find a plane that is perpendicular to this line and it's distance from the origin is exactly 3.

My try:

The normal of the plane is the same as the vector $s = (2,2,1)$

Then we need to position it: $$x^2+y^2+z^2 = \pm 9$$

from the line we get:
$$x = 2t$$
$$y = 2t-4$$
$$z = t+3$$

We input into the equation:$x^2+y^2+z^2 = \pm 9$
and we get a complex solution for $9t^2-2t+25 = \pm 9$.

Where have I done the mistake?

The official solution is: $2x + 2y + z = \pm 9$

Comment: You cannot have $ x^2+y^2+z^2=-9$

Answer (score 1):

From your parametric equation of the line, you get the vector ditector which is
$$\vec{v}=(a,b,c)=(2,2,1)$$

this vector must be normal to the plane.

So, the cartesian equation of the plane will be as
$$ax+by+cz-d=0$$
or
$$2x+2y+z-d=0$$

its distance to the origine is
$$\frac{|2.0+2.0+1.0-d|}{\sqrt{2^2+2^2+1^2}}=3$$

thus $$d=\pm 9$$